# Java. Задачка по функциональному интерфейсу

Tags: java, lambda

Вот условие:

> You need to write your own functional interface (TernaryIntPredicate)
>   and use it with a lambda expression. The interface must have a single
>   non-static (and non-default) method test with three int arguments that
>   returns boolean value.
>
> Besides, you need to write a lambda expression with three int
>   arguments using your TernaryIntPredicate.
>
> The lambda expression has to return true if all passed values are
>   different otherwise false. The name of the instance is
>   allValuesAreDifferentPredicate. It should be a static field.
>   Important. Use the provided template for your solution. Do not change it!
>   Sample Input 1: 1 1 1
>   Sample Output 1: False
>   Sample Input 2: 2 3 4
>   Sample Output 2: True

Вот начальный код:

```
    @FunctionalInterface
public interface TernaryIntPredicate {
// Write a method here
}

public static final TernaryIntPredicate allValuesAreDifferentPredicate = // 
Write a lambda expression here
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос/проблема?

Comment: Да, разобрался уже, спасибо, вот код итоговый (та часть которая не была реализована ниже у Влада) , всё компилируется в Intellij Idea, но в Stepik (куда надо вбивать код на проверку) всё равно ошибки выдает:
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
        int first = scan.nextInt();  
        int second = scan.nextInt();  
        int third = scan.nextInt();  
        System.out.println(allValuesAreDifferentPredicate.test(first, second,   third));  
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TernaryIntPredicate {
    boolean test(int first, int second, int third);
}

class Main {
    public static final TernaryIntPredicate allValuesAreDifferentPredicate =
            (first, second, third) -> first != second && first != third && second != third;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(allValuesAreDifferentPredicate.test(1,1,1));
        System.out.println(allValuesAreDifferentPredicate.test(2,3,4));
    }
}
```

Comment: тут немного другое задание. Надо вводить через консоль 3 любые цифры, после чего, в случае, если они равны (как в примере 1 1 1), то false, если нет - true. Я так понимаю это через Scanner надо сделать.

Comment: @ВикторКондратюк в приведённом вами тексте задание именно такое, на какое дан ответ.

Comment: @ВладЛеонидов Внизу задания написано Sample Input - это образец ввода данных. Пользователь должен ввести в консоль три значения и в ответ уже получить true или false. В любом случае спасибо, ваш вариант близок к верному.

Comment: В задании не указано, как именно должен осуществляться ввод, да и это пример для вас, ну а прикрутить чтение с консоли, думаю, сможете сами.